# Using Mechanize to download a file with multi-threads?

Tags: ruby, http, mechanize

**How to use Mechanize to download a file more faster**

Is there a way to get the content-length before downloading a file, and then divide it into parts, so that I can download it by using multithreads?

I've tried `agent.get(uri, 'Range'=>'bytes=0-499')`, but it downloaded the whole file. Anybody  show me the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way. Not only is mechanize not thread safe, but also http does not allow you to request part of a document.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -I -H Range:bytes=0-11 http://photocdn.sohu.com/20100125/Img269812337.jpg
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 12
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 26 Feb 2012 16:49:36 GMT
Server: SWS
Cache-Control: max-age=5184000
Expires: Thu, 26 Apr 2012 16:49:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Jan 2010 05:42:55 GMT
FSS-Cache: HIT from 27722327.31785751.38755221
Content-Range: bytes 0-11/36161
```

3 Notice:

1. Range Headers are only support in HTTP1.1([rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35))
2. Not all servers handle Range Headers
3. The Content-Range HTTP Response Headers tell the Content Length of your requested resources

Comment: **Thanks!** By using `net/http`, I can download a file separately with specific ranges, But not in parallel. When I trying to use multi-threads, it always downloads the last part of the file. :-(